# Ubuntu 18.04 with Bluetooth and Aerplnane Mode

Tags: bluetooth

These "problems" don't stop me working but I am wondering why?
My Thinkpad T580 is connected by cable and the Wi-Fi is turned off.
Several times a day when I notice the little icons on the Taskbar I switch off both Bluetooth and Aeroplane mode (which shouldn't change anything with a wired connection?) but they keep coming back. 
Is there any way to switch them off so permanently whilst retaining the possibility of bringing them back in case I should need to?
Garoolgan

Comment: It looks as if I leave Aeroplane mode on, which doesn't interfere with a cable connection, the WiFi and Bluethooth stay off.  This to me is sort of logical.  I'll confirm this after a few day's trials......

Comment: I'm confirming that now for over 24 hours, since I've left Aeroplane Mode on, both WiFi and Bluetooth stay Off.